# How do I exclude tags from being parsed in TinyMCE WYSIWYG?

Tags: parsing, tinymce, bbcode

I am using TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor to create posts in my custom forum.  I am using the bbCode plugin.  I want to add a quote post feature.  I need to add [quote id=123]Some Original Message[/quote] to the editor without it being parsed.

I tried putting that string inside the textarea tags, but it just shows up as "Some Original Message".

Comment: can you create tinymce fiddle or live example for this?